# return from a function which changes pointer address, address stays the same

Tags: c, visual-studio

I wrote a more complex program but I have narrowed down my problem to the following one: 
Why is this program printing down junk and not hzllo? I have followed the values and memory address of temp and p with the debugger and it returns from the foo function correctly and for a reason I don't understand prints junk.

```
void foo(char **str) {
    char temp[79];
    strcpy_s(temp,79,*str);
    *(temp + 1) = 'z';

    *str = temp;    

}

void main() {

    char *p = (char*) malloc(79 * sizeof(char));
    p = "hello";
    foo(&p);

    printf("%s", p);
}
```

Comment: You realize that the first line of `main` does nothing at all, short of producing an instant memory leak? (The `malloc` really belongs inside the function `foo`!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
char temp[79];        # allocated on the stack, vanishes on return
```

...to...

```
static char temp[79]; # has a longer lifetime
```

Also, you don't need the `malloc(3)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. But I still have a question. Why would I need it that temp to be defined as static? I understand that trying to call by value will not work since temp is local.So I am calling by reference, why isn't it enough?

Comment: @Kerrek, quite true of course, tho the OP is looking for enlightenment at this point, not grad school, so, one step at a time. He clearly wants to modify a pointer via double indirection and that's a reasonable lesson to proceed with.

Comment: @Steinfeld, your call by ref was quite correct and is working fine. The problem is: *what did you point at?*  Well, you used the address of a local. It's lifetime-limited to the duration of the function call instance. Specifically, it's allocated on the stack. When the function returns everything is popped off the stack and that memory will be reused on the next function call, and that would be the `printf()` instance. You need something more persistent if you want it to still be there after `foo()` returns.

Answer (score 4):

`temp` is a local variable, which goes out of scope when you exit `foo`. Thus `p` is a dangling pointer and your program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(char **str) {
    // Bad: "temp" doesn't exist when the function returns
    char temp[79];
    strcpy_s(temp,79,*str);
    *(temp + 1) = 'z';

    *str = temp;    

}

void main() {

    char *p = (char*) malloc(79 * sizeof(char));
    p = "hello";
    foo(&p);

    printf("%s", p);
}
```

This is better:

```
void foo(char **str) {
    // This should change the pointer ... to something valid outside the function
    *str = (*str) + 1;        
}
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your answer.

Comment: I was trying to make two points: 1) returning a pointer to "temp" is evil, and 2) it shows one example of changing the pointer.  `*str = (*str)+1` causes "p" to point to "ello" (instead of "hello").